# Is there any way to do a task for each member of a list without loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a large number of array in pandas with 256 row and 5 columns and I would like to calculate statistical(min, max, mean, ....) features for 4 members of array in each column. i wrote the following code but it is so time-consuming:

```
for col in array:
    for j in range(0,256,1):
        min = array[col].iloc[j:j+4].min()
        max= array[col].iloc[j:j+4].max()
        (other functions)
```

as I have many array and i would like to do this task for each array it is very  time consuming. is there any way to write a simpler code without loop that decreases the time of execution.

Comment: Um, *what exactly are you dealing with here*. `iloc` is likely for some `pandas` data structure.

Comment: may data structure is in pandas but i try to ask my question in easy way

Comment: Not giving the details does not make it easy. It makes it not well defined.

Comment: something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479607/pandas-min-of-selected-row-and-columns

Comment: yes it is similar but it want to do this task without for loop

Comment: This looks like windowing: easy for *avg*, challenging for *min*, *max*. `but it is so time-consuming` & `without [loop/for]`: you are faced with problem X (something taking more time than you are willing to invest) and ask for a solution to [problem Y](http://xyproblem.info/) (how to achieve the same effect without one particular language construct). `simpler code without loop that decreases the time` looping isn't *increasing* processing time, but have a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html).

Comment: I am not sure if you can apply a function to each n/4 elements without using up O(n) time.

Comment: (@Unni: sadly, it isn't even n/k, but 2n/k (entry&exit window/window size), and constants worsened. Either the link to statistics triggers *affordable approximate results using sampling* - or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate min and max for 4 consecutive elements of a `pandas.DataFrame`?

This can be done using pandas `rolling`:

```
df.rolling(4).agg(['min', 'max']).shift(-3)
```

The shift is necessary as the default for pandas is to have the window right aligned.